# "Using" statement doesn't import namespace?

Tags: powershell

I have a script where I use the `System.Windows.Forms` namespace to create a WinForm. I put `using namespace System.Windows.Forms` at the top of the script, but when it gets to trying to access any of those types, it throws an "Unable to find type" error. Here's my code:

```
using namespace System.Windows.Forms

function New-GUI {
    $script:form = [System.Windows.Forms.Form]::new()
}
```

Error:

> Unable to find type [System.Windows.Forms.Form].

Am I misunderstanding how `using` is used? I thought it imports any specified namespaces. And from [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_using), it seems like that's the case so I don't know why it isn't working.

So how does `using` work? And is that the best method to do what I'm trying to do or should I just go with `Add-Type` instead? What's the difference between `using` and `Add-Type`?

Comment: `using namespace` does not load an assembly and "If you are not creating new PowerShell classes, use the Add-Type cmdlet instead (of `using assembly`). For more information, see Add-Type." as stated in that doc.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon gotcha, thanks. That quote is from the `using assembly` section, so I wasn't sure if it applied to `using namespace`.